# Efficient row operation on numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to run an operation (e.g. subtracting the median) on rows of a numpy array.

One way to do that is using comprehension lists:

```
import numpy as np
from statistics import median 
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7 ,8], [9, 10, 11, 12]])

xm = np.vstack(([x[i,:] - median(x[i,:]) for i in range(x.shape[0])]))
```

Each row is processed, then stacked vertically as numpy array.

Is there a more efficient/elegant way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x - np.median(x, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
```

given `np.median` has a `keepdims` parameter you can also avoid the manual slicing to make it broadcasting-friendly

```
x - np.median(x, axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

if you want to apply an arbitrary function row by row, like `median` from `statistics`, you can use `np.apply_along_axis`, just beware it's basically a `for` loop so you don't really get any vectorization speedup:

```
x - np.apply_along_axis(median, axis=1, x)[:,np.newaxis]
```

Comment: What if the operation has no axis option. e.g.  median from python statistics library ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `statistics` library, I guess you could use `np.apply_along_axis(median, 1, x)` but it's not as efficent as numpy native one

Comment: @Nir There is no difference between `numpy`'s `median` and `statistics`' `median` - they should return the same results in all situations except they behave slightly differently when input is an empty list. I would just use `numpy` version.